# Why is Java caching my app while trying to develop it

Tags: java, xcode, safari, environment

i'm trying to build a Java applet and i'm having a major problem trying to set up my development environment because my applet has bugs in it but I can't fix them easilly because Java won't get the latest version of the applet. I've turned off caching in "Java Preferences.app".

I want to set it so that applet **wil not be cached at all**, as any bugs can easilly be ironed out.

I'm using the latest (on Leopard) XCode and Safari 4.

Thanx,
kenny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Applet Caching](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/guide/misc/appletcaching.html)

> SUMMARY:This new feature is activated
>   by including the new PARAM
>   NAME="cache_option" and PARAM
>   NAME="cache_archive" values in the tag
>   that specifies the use of Java Plug-in
>   as below:  The cache_option attribute
>   can take one of three values:
>
> **No**
>
> Disable applet installation. Always
>   download the file from the web server.
>
> **Browser**
>
> Run applets from the browser cache
>   (default).
>
> **Plugin**
>
> Run applets from the new Java Plug-in
>   cache.

EDIT:

[Caching Option](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/applet_caching.html#option)

[Steps to Turn off Java Applet Caching](http://cyclic.ucsd.edu/javafiles.html)

Comment: thanks but it never work - i found a workaround in the Java Console

Comment: aha! i didn't read your post properly! only added cache_option... i needed both! THANKS :D